# PHP Excel isDateTime not working

Tags: php, excel, date

I'd like some help to solve a problem with the PHP Excel library to import a cell data.

In my script I need to check if a cell is formatted as a date, using "PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime".

For some date cells, the format is flagged by MS Excel like this :
"Date formats that begin with an asterisk (*) respond to changes in regional date and time settings that are specified for the Operating System."

And for thoses cells, the test PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime fails, I obtain this :

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filepath);

$objexcel = $reader->load($filepath);

$cell = $objexcel->getSheet()->getCell('A2');

var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)); // return false

echo $cell->getFormattedValue(); // return timestamp : 43466
```

When I convert my xlsx file in xls file or when I give another date format to my cell, it works, I obtain this :

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filepath);

$objexcel = $reader->load($filepath);

$cell = $objexcel->getSheet()->getCell('A2');

var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)); // return true

echo $cell->getFormattedValue(); // return 2019-01-01
```

The "setReadDataOnly" is still at false for my reader.

Does someone has any idea to fix it ?

(I precise that i'm in France, and we write dates at format 'd/m/Y')

Thanks in advance for helping me.